# csv table to postgresql db with nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, csv

Hey guys i cant implement the function in nodejs what can parse data from csv to postgresql table. Can u help with this question?

I'm trying to use the csv-stream library and can get the datas in console, but how to do an import to postgresql no idea.

```
var csvStream = csv.createStream(options);


fs.createReadStream(process.argv[2]).pipe(csvStream)
.on('error', function (err) {
console.error(err);
})
.on('data', function (data) {
    // outputs an object containing a set of key/value pair representing a line found in the csv file.
   // console.log(data);
})
.on('column', function (key, value) {
// outputs the column name associated with the value found
// console.log('#' + key + ' = ' + value);
console.log('# ' + value);

})
```

**UPDATE**

```
var pg = require("pg");

var conString = "pg://admin:guest@localhost:5432/Employees";

var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();

var query = client.query("SELECT firstname, lastname FROM emps ORDER BY lastname, firstname");
```

and now how i can get this select query to csv?

**UPDATE 0.1**

```
var pg = require('pg');
var csv = require('csv');
var csvWriter = require('csv-write-stream')
var conString = "pg://admin:admin@localhost:5432/labels";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();
var sql = "COPY test TO 'personss.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"
var query = client.query("SELECT firstname, lastname FROM test ORDER BY lastname, firstname");
query.on("row", function (row, result) {
    result.addRow(row);
});
query.on("end", function (result) {
    console.log((result.rows, null, "    "));
    client.end();
});
```

Now probably i need to do each cycles in result.row.

Comment: you will hear about `COPY` in comments :) meanwhile take a look at https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres

Comment: @VaoTsun That `COPY` implementation is buggy and poorly supported ;)

Comment: I've done it properly in the past, and more than once, but won't have a chance to provide a proper answer before this weekend. Basically, you pull your CSV records in batches, and you insert them in the same batches (1-to-1), by generating multi-row inserts. Also, you can optionally wrap this all into a transaction, depending on the requirements.

Comment: instead of csv can we stream multiple insert statements directly into postgres using Copy test !