# csv insert with pg library in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, csv

So i did that kind of code.

```
var csv = require('csv-stream');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "pg://admin:admin@localhost:5432/labels";

// All of these arguments are optional. 
var options = {
    delimiter : ';', // default is , 
    endLine : '\n', // default is \n, 
    escapeChar : '"', // default is an empty string 
    enclosedChar : '"', // default is an empty string 

}
try {


var csvStream = csv.createStream(options);
fs.createReadStream('personss.csv').pipe(csvStream)
.on('error', function (err) {
    console.error(err);
})
.on('data', function (data) {
    // outputs an object containing a set of key/value pair representing     a line found in the csv file. 
    console.log(data);

    pg.connect(conString, function (err, client, done) {
            client.query(
                'INSERT into test (firstname, lastname) from', 
        function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('data inserted');
                    }
                });

    });
});
} catch (e) {
console(e.message);
};
```

where i stream the csv file with csv-stream library, how i can insert now that values from variable 'data' to my database? Should i do it by for cycle?

**Update**

added for cycle to iterate data

```
pg.connect(conString, function (err, client, done) {
        for (var i = 0; data.length; i++) {
            client.query(
                'INSERT into test (firstname, lastname)',
        function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('data inserted' + result.data[0]);
                    }
                });
        };
    });
```

Comment: Why did you publish 2 questions about the same here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911500/csv-table-to-postgresql-db-with-nodejs. Keep it to one question, and try to maintain it.

Comment: just thinked that it gonna be better ;)